# unit testing using VSTS wcf service in c#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, unit-testing

- I am trying to test my wcf service using the test suite in TFS.

  - I have a wcf service in Solution called **Inspector**.
  - In that the config file is in **InspectorHost** Project
  - There are helper Methods in **MessageInspector** project.
  - In this there is a method called   **CallIssService**.
  - This **IssService** is the Service used by **MessageInspector** Project.
  - Though the service reference is in this project,the Config file is in **InspectorHost**  project.
  - The test method generated for this method is **CallIssServiceTest.cs**.
  - Here is the porblem. When I try to run the test on this method the test fails and the error is "**The URL to test is not specified. Tests configured to run in ASP.NET must specify a valid URL**". The URL it is asking is the **URL of the IssService**   the MessageInspector  Project is using.

Here is the code for test method. `

```
    /// <summary>
    ///A test for CallIss
    ///</summary>
    [TestMethod()] 
    [DeploymentItem("Inspector.MessageInspector.dll")]
    public void CallIssServiceTest()
    {
        CustomUserNameValidator_Accessor target = new CustomUserNameValidator_Accessor();
        target._userName = "tempUserName";
        target._password = "temptemp";

        Identity expected = new Identity();
        expected.UserID = "tempUserName";
        expected.board = new Board();
        expected.board.Code = "013";

        Identity actual;
        actual = target.CallIAA();
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.UserID, actual.UserID);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.board.Code, actual.board.Code);  
    }
```

`

Here is the class to be tested.

```
    using IssService;
    /// <summary>
    /// This calles the Iss Service to Authenticate the user
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Identity CallIssService()
    {
        Identity userIdentity = 
         new IssServiceClient().VerifyUser(_userName, _password, null);
        return userIdentity;
    }
```

Can some body please help me understand what is the mistake I am doing or is there anything more to be done in this context.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,
Chand.

Answer (score 0):

Fix ([this link helped me.](http://forums.asp.net/p/1454799/3605020.aspx))

---

1) In the LocalTestRun.testrunConfigfile/deployment the Web.Config file in host project is selected.Click Apply and save this.

2) A RenameWebConfig.bat file is added in the folder of test project with below one line of code indicating it to copy the Web.config file and rename it every time there is a new build.

**rename web.config UAWebService.TestProject.dll.config**

Hence the issue of Config settings not visible to the test project is defeated. 
Wonder why Microsoft skipped this aspect ;)